# Check if field has value (content)

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have code which checks if field exists, but I try to change it to check if field has value (content) or not.

In views I have one field to show all content (Rewrite results). So all fields are loaded always. Thats why I need code which checks does field have content or not.

This is what I got now, but it adds "has_no_field" to all - no matter if field_image has content or not.

```
function theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $rows = $vars['rows'];

foreach ($vars['view']->result as $id => $row) {

    if (isset($row->field_image['und'][0]['value']) == 1) {
      $vars['classes_array'][$id] = 'has_field';
    }  
    else {
      $vars['classes_array'][$id] = 'has_no_field';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing

```
if (isset($row->field_image['und'][0]['value']) == 1) {
```

to

```
if (!empty($row->field_field_image)) {
```

Comment: Still adding "has_no_field" to all rows - no matter if there is image or not.

Comment: @hene I've updated the answer. Observe the extra field_ in front of field_image. Had to have a look myself and just noticed that :)